# What is the modulation technique used?

Tags: rf, modulation, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation

I own a Tx/Rx Radio Direction-Finding (RDF) set for a sport called falconry, basically, locating & recovering a pet falcon after flight.

The Tx tag is at **218.025MHz** from **Marshall Radio Telemetry** :
[image: Marshal Radio RDF Tag]

The Rx is a 10-channel receiver, **TRX-10S**, from **Wildlife Materials Inc.** :
[image: TRX-10S]

I believe all systems for wildlife tracking from different manufacturers are compatible and speak the same modulation language.

Now, I want to know the modulation technique used by the Tx tag, I have my beloved **Rigol DSA815-TG** spectrum analyzer, but the problem is that, as with all RDF beacons, the signals they transmit are intermittent. They have the famous "Tet...Tet...Tet..." beep fashion... so I can't see the spectral content for an adequate amount of time -- and that is only when I'm able to pick it up (some times the spectrum analyzer misses it...)

My -clear- questions are :

1. What is the modulation technique used in those wildlife tracking beacons?
2. Whether I knew a straight answer to (1.) or not, what is a reasonable setup with my Rigol to see the signal?

---

For reference:

Tx Link : [Marshal Radio RT Standard](http://www.marshallradio.com/gulf-region-falconry-falconry/gulf-region-falconry-transmitters/item/272-rt-standard-transmitter)

Rx Link : [TRX-10S](http://wildlifematerials.com/store/product.php?s=m&id=88&cat=)

Comment: Links to ALL devices would help the profoundly lazy and might in turn help you

Comment: I believe (without evidence) that pulsed DF beacons are generally CW.  Refer wikipedia.

Comment: @Andyaka : You have a great reputation buddy (I loved your digital filters PDF)

I will add the links, but I assure you, there are no decent datasheets :D

Tx Link : [Marshal Radio RT Standard](http://www.marshallradio.com/gulf-region-falconry-falconry/gulf-region-falconry-transmitters/item/272-rt-standard-transmitter)
Rx Link : [TRX-10S](http://wildlifematerials.com/store/product.php?s=m&id=88&cat=)

Comment: @markt : I know, it feels that way :D but the question is CW FM or CW AM Or CW Narrow-Band FM

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a spectrum analyzer you might be best to use a receiver that can stay locked on the 218.025MHz carrier. One cheap option that works well at that frequency is a USB TV tuner capable of being used by SDR (software defined radio) software. For example see the [RTL-SDR](http://www.rtl-sdr.com/about-rtl-sdr/) page.

There are quite a few software options listed at the bottom of the page but personally I've found the [SDR#](http://www.sdrsharp.com/) software to be good if you're running Windows. In the case of a periodic signal you'll also be able to capture it to a wave file for later analysis. Having said that I agree with the comment by markt that it’s likely to just be CW.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful I'll try buying one..

(too bad I don't have sufficient reputation to vote your answer up)

Comment: That's OK, at some point you could accept the answer but I'd leave it a while yet - maybe someone is familiar with that particular product and knows exactly how it works.

Comment: No not yet, I don't accept it yet as a final answer.